# GWT force Update on Server during development mode

Tags: java, gwt

I am getting a really annoying problem. In my application, whenever i need to change client code, the refresh make the new fix works

However, when editing server code, i need to stop the current application and run again. When the application is big, this takes a little time.

Is there a way to force update the current running server code???

Comment: what are you using as server jetty, or tomcat?.

Comment: Well, jetty because that comes with eclipse. By the way, can we use another one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i need to stop the current application and run again
>
> [...]
>   Is there a way to force update the current running server code???

Absolutely! It's not necessary to stop the server when you need to refresh the server side code: In the "Development Mode" view (in Eclipse), click the icon with the two yellow arrows. This application reload is much quicker than a server restart.

[image]

Comment: What about non-Eclipse users?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse run your back-end application in debug mode instead of run mode and that usually gets you a little closer due to its incremental compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on how to use an external server with GWT http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's

Answer (score 0):

Run your server side code in some other server like tomcat. And start the gwt application in noserver mode. But if you change any rpc related classes in client side you have redeploy the code in tomcat server.