# GWT + Eclipse : refresh without restarting server

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT project on Eclipse.
When editing server code, i need to stop the current application and run again if I want to see the changes in the browser. It is annoying

Is there a way to force update the current running server code?

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557342/gwt-force-update-on-server-during-development-mode), it simply does not work, when I click the Refresh icon with the small yellow arrows, the console says refresh is successful but I do not see the changes in the browser.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by downloading the newest GWT Toolkit into Eclipse